# Which 3D Engine for iPad development?

Tags: ipad

I have built a couple of games on the iPad using core animation, but for my next project I would like to built a 3D game. I am not really comfortable with programming OpenGL directly and would also like the toolset that usually comes with a mature 3D engine project. I have used Ogre3D on the PC before and was very happy with that, but I wasn't sure if it had been ported to the iPad specifically and if there were better alternatives available.

What engines have used and can recommend? Specifically I am interested in:

- Cost
- Tool support
- Data import functionality

Comment: Ogre3D has an iPhone/iPad SDK. Since you're familiar with Ogre, you should probably give it a try ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Unity 3d](http://unity3d.com) - I've played around with the engine on PC and Mac, but not the iPad/iPhone.  I have used games on the iPod touch made with this engine though.  Works very well from what I've seen.

Unity iPhone 1.7 works with the iPad.  You can use basic Unity3D for free to develop/prototype a game, then upgrade/buy the iPhone version.