# An Ogre3D iPhone 'Hello World' project?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ogre

I have been [investigating](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/581/which-3d-engine-for-ipad-development) various 3d engines for iPhone/iPad development and have mostly decided to use [Ogre3d](http://www.ogre3d.org/).  I have got the SDK, the iPhone [dependancies](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogre/files/), built and run the *SampleBrowser* project on the simulator and (with some difficulty) my 3GS. My problem is with the complexity of the *SampleBrowser* project.

It is a cross platform project, which (at this point) I am not interested in supporting and pre-loads all the Ogre tech samples (some of which don't work on the iPhone). What I really need is a very simple bare bones *Hello World* XCode project to start work with. If someone knows where I can find one, I would appreciate it. If not, building one is the next thing on my todo list.

I have [posted](https://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=59296#p398720) the same question on the Ogre forums, so if I get some feedback there, I will update here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, the Ogre guys have a cut down [template project](https://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=59296#p398720) that you can use as a basis to build Ogre XCode projects.

If you have [downloaded and installed the SDK](http://www.ogre3d.org/download) (i.e. haven't built the source yourself), you can just install the [Ogre XCode templates](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogre/files/) and they will build and run out of the box.

If you have built the source from the [Mercurial repo](http://www.ogre3d.org/developers/mercurial), you can find the template projects in the *SDK/OSX/Xcode templates* directory of the SDK. You might have to play around with library and include directories to get it working, as they assume the layout of the prebuilt SDK.