# What 3D engine should I use for the browser, iPhone, and Android platforms?

Tags: browser-based-games

I have a C++ game that has a 3D engine that works only in Windows. I'm wondering which engine I should use so that it can be used in a browser or in iPad (iPhone) and Android environments? Does anyone have an idea of the size of the task to migrate from one 3D engine to another?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/581/which-3d-engine-for-ipad-development

Answer (score 8):

There are only two engines I know of that work on iPhone, Android, and in a browser:

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) and [ShiVa 3D](http://www.stonetrip.com/).

> Does anyone have an idea of the size of the task to migrate from one 3D engine to another?

This isn't an answerable question as-is.  How much code you have and what engine you're using are going to matter.

I don't know about Shiva, but in Unity you're going to need to rewrite all your game code to one of the languages they support: C# or Javascript.

Comment: +1. Unity seems to be the answer to most "Which game engine?" questions

Comment: @Ray Unity is our Jquery.

Answer (score 2):

ShiVa personally would be the better pick. "The ShiVa Authoring Tool is available for Windows, Mac, Linux, Wii, iPhone, iPad, Android, HP WebOS and Airplay SDK for free." Unlike unity which is only Windows and Mac, iphone and Android.

Comment: That's only an issue if you actually want to target those platforms which the asker does not specify.  Unity does support Wii.  It also supports PS3 and 360, which arguably are significantly more important than HP WebOS and Airplay-supported platforms.  I'm not going to touch whether or not supporting Linux is important.

Comment: I was under the impression that Unity also supported X360, Wii and PS3.

Comment: `Android environments` IMO counts as a linux based Platform. I don't see why i have to get -2 count though